# Error: "boot configuration data setting 0x25000020 has changed for the following boot application \windows\system32\winload.efi"

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, utorrent, bcd

Yesterday I got a suspicious message when starting uTorrent, it said "The install of 'some temporary file.tmp' failed (signer certificate mismatch)". The file was an exe file with .tmp extension and signed with the "Bittorrent Inc" signature. After powering off the PC and booting again, I got this message: "Bitlocker needs your recovery key to unlock your drive because the boot configuration data setting 0x25000020 has changed for the following boot application \windows\system32\winload.efi"
It seems it means that the BCD nx option has changed, and when I checked it was set to "OptIn"
Question: can this be a result of virus activity on my PC? What should I do?

Comment: You don’t specify what you were downloading with BitTorrent, but I would imagine, that activity is to blame.  hopefully you have your the BitLocker recovery key since there is no workaround to decrypting your files without it.

Comment: @Ramhound nothing was downloading at that moment. I do have the key, but I'm concerned that my PC might be compromised.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit?s=3|0.0000

Comment: @user626528 - You have not provided enough information to determine if malicious software exists on your system.

Comment: @Ramhound I provided all the information that I have. The main question is: can uTorrent be a source of infection?

Comment: @user626528 - Most security software will flag uTorrent has to be malicious for many reasons.  As for it being malicious, that is something only you can decide, most likely you downloaded something that was malicious through uTorrent.  I don't know what you were using uTorrent to download so I cannot determine if that's the case.

Comment: @Ramhound as I wrote before, nothing was downloading at that moment.

Comment: @@Ramhound your info is incorrect, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this was a potentially-unwanted-app named PUA:Win32/CandyOpen - see https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/threats/malware-encyclopedia-description?Name=PUA%3aWin32%2fCandyOpen
And most likely, it **was** dropped by uTorrent as the payload files were signed by Bittorrent Inc.
Be warned.